# AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I was not expecting this error ("AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'plot'") and have not been able to find the exact error. I am thinking its not the exact error because plotly obviously has plotting abilities and that somewhere along the way my data isnt formatted correctly, for this particular exercise.

I am open to suggestions on new methods. This is just what I used because it was easy to follow, its what I want in the end, and its centralized.

Error occurs on last line `py.plot( fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map' )`

I have copied the code from the example: [United States Choropleth Map](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/)

And here is my code:

```
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

py.tools.set_credentials_file(username='user', api_key='xxxXxxXxxx')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("C:/Users/d/Documents/Personal/Python Scripts/Python/Connect.csv")

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
df[['Open Balance','Amount', 'Aging']] = df[['Open Balance','Amount', 
    'Aging']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df[['Date', 'Due Date']] = df[['Date','Due Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

state_total_byitem = df.groupby(by = ['State', 'Item']).agg({'Open Balance':'sum','Amount':'sum','Paid':'count','Aging':'mean'})
sti = state_total_byitem
sti.reset_index(level=['State', 'Item'], inplace=True)

for col in sti.columns:
    sti[col] = sti[col].astype(str)

sti['text'] = 'State ' + sti['State'] + ' Item ' + sti['Item'] + '<br>' +\
    ' Open Balance ' + sti['Open Balance'] + ' Paid ' + sti['Paid'] + '<br>' +\
    ' Amount ' + sti['Amount'] + ' Aging ' + sti['Aging']

scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(220,224,225)'],[0.2, 'rgb(204,220,224)'],[0.4, 'rgb(158,192,200)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(100,166,184)'],[0.8, 'rgb(60,175,206)'],[1.0, 'rgb(10,206,255)']]

data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = sti['State'],
        z = sti['Amount'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = sti['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            ) ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "$ in USD")
        ) ]

layout = dict(
        title = 'Invoices by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
            showlakes = True,
            lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'),
             )

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
py.plot( fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map' )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
import plotly as py
```

You should have

```
import plotly.plotly as py
```

For future reference, try to get a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. Oftentimes it will help you find the error on your own.

Comment: I will review the link (MVCE) and try harder next time, It may look like I know things but I know absolutely nothing and my background is excel- haha. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DavisVance No worries, I asked much worse questions when I got started. Don't forget, if an answer has solved your problem, accept it and upvote it (:

Comment: I have `import plotly.plotly as py` and have a related error: `AttributeError: module 'plotly.plotly' has no attribute 'plot'`

Comment: @Revolucion for Monica: `import ploty.plotly; plotly.plot()` did not work for me either. Using an alias did: `import ploty.plotly as py; py.plot()`. If you write `plotly.plot()`, this seems to call the outer Plotly module. So, if you do not use an alias, you need to write `plotly.plotly.plot()`. Enoug "plots" for now.